# How to create a TimescaleDB Hypertable from Django models?

Tags: django, postgresql, timescaledb

By defining a Django model, you can't create a hypertable in TimescaleDB, I got an error like: `Cannot create a unique index without using the partitioning key` with the following (example) model:

```py
class Record(models.Model):
    class State(models.Choices):
        ONLINE = "online"
        OFFLINE = "offline"

    time = models.DateTimeField()

    mode = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=Mode.choices)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=State.choices)
```

Does anyone know how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/issues/447, this can be solved by defining the `time` field as the primary key.

```py
time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True, primary_key=True)
```